# Test if a sample sequence is asymptotically linear

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose I have a sequence of points $(x_n,y_n)$ for $n\geq 1$ and I hypothesize that the sequence is asymptotically linear, in the sense that there is a unique linear function $L$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\geq 1$ such that $|L(x_n)-y_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

An example of this would be the sequence $(n,q(n))$ where $q(x)=\frac{x^2}{x+1}$. This function has a slant asymptote of $y=x$ as $x\to\infty$, and the samples at integer $x$ make it apparent.

So, what is the test to determine this? Note that this is distinct from linear regression because I can ignore any finite initial sequence.

---

My idea is to use a p-value as follows. Suppose we have points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\dots,(x_N,y_N)$. For each $m=1,2,\dots,N−1$, there is an associated linear regression on the points $(x_m,y_m),(x_{m+1},y_{m+1}),\dots,(x_N,y_N)$ with some $p$-value $p_m$.

Assuming that initial segment of the sequence are very non-linear (as in my example) then $p_m$ may be large for $m\approx 1$. Similarly, for $m\approx N$ we have a very small sample size so again $p_m$ is too large. Therefore we expect there is some $m^*$ and associated $p^*$ such that $p^*$ is minimal.

I would like to judge the asymptotic linearity of my sequence by $p^*$ I just defined, since it does not depend on my choice of $m$ and should be relatively low when the sequence is asymptotically linear.

Comment: Does this problem have any similarity to the estimation of the minimum or the maximum of a distribution? In that you really only care about the end of your sample. I think non-linearity does not guarantee that you get a high p-value for $m=1$. E.g., you can still get low p-value if you’re on the positive segment of a quadratic function. Just the fit won’t be so good.

Comment: It isn't logically possible to test your theory with any finite amount of data because, as you point out, literally *any* behavior in a finite amount of data is consistent with this characterization of asymptotic linearity.

Comment: @whuber That is my fear. But surely, there is a way to differentiate between a highly erratic sequence vs. a sequence which quickly settles to linear using some sort of test statistics.

Comment: Intuitively that's right--but doing so requires a more specific model of what you mean by "quickly settles to linear."  Because you have abstracted this question from whatever the motivating application might be, we have no way of helping you with that formulation.  You need to either (a) describe that formulation or (b) provide a quantitative model with enough information to allow us to suggest appropriate test procedures.